# VSCode - Debugger for Chrome -- Can't get debugger to work with an Webpack stack

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm using Webpack + Webpack dev server + BrowserSync and use ES6 JS. I would like to pair this stack with VSCode Debugger for Chrome but after many hours of trying things out I still can't get it to work properly.

The debugger is ignoring my breakpoints and ends up walking through some imported modules instead. With some settings (Webpack sourcemap settings I recall) it walks over the breakpoints but the code is compiled so highly unreadable.

Current source maps setting in Webpack (works well in Chrome):

```
devtool: 'eval-source-map'
```

VSCode launch:

```
{
    "name": "Launch",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "url": "http://localhost:3000",
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "diagnosticLogging": true,
    "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
}
```

Comment: Use the `.scripts` command to check whether it resolves your local sources correctly. Use the sourceMapPathOverrides setting if needed. Otherwise check the extension readme. There isn't enough info here to help you.

Comment: I can't find any details about the `.script` command on Google except for an Unix terminal command. Could you clarify what you meant? I checked in the Debug Console log for a file with the name of my js file but can't find anything. Just the style file shows up.

Comment: When no errors are found and I press pause, the debugger shows some of the node modules I use. When I create an error somewhere in the code, the debugger crashes, F5 doesn't respond and the debugger can only be activated by launching by clicking on the green play button.

Comment: It's in the readme for the extension. There are lots of debugging tips there: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome